# AJAX call with JSON data return

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have set up a JSFiddle to learn about deferred objects / JSON / AJAX: http://jsfiddle.net/4HxSr/85/

I have got the code to the point where I am successfully posting a request to JSFiddle's echo URL, with my JSON data but when I look at the GET response, there is nothing in it.  I have managed to iterate over the JSON array and display the elements and its properties, but I'm not sure what I need to change to access the JSON data from the AJAX response.  Is this possible to practice in JSFiddle?

Here is the jQuery code from fiddle:

```
$(function () {

    var item = {
        "Stores": [{
            "Store": {
                "username": "matt",
                    "item1": "test1",
                    "Latitude": "-68.480280"
            }
        }, {
            "Store": {
                "username": "tim",
                    "item1": "test2",
                    "Latitude": "59.408408"
            }
        }, {
            "Store": {
                "username": "greg",
                    "item1": "test3",
                    "Latitude": "59.408408"
            }
        }]
    }

        function myAJAX() {
            return $.ajax({
                url: '/echo/json',
                type: 'POST',
                data: item,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json'
            });
        }
        //fired when defferred object is resolved
        myAJAX().done(function (data) {
            var counter = 0;
            var html = '';
            $.each(item.Stores, function (index, item) {
                counter++;

                $.each(this, function (k, v) {
                    html += "<li>Store" + counter + " Username = " + this.username + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>Store" + counter + " item1 = " + this.item1 + "</li>";
                    html += "<li>Store" + counter + " Latitude = " + this.Latitude + "</li>";
                });
            });
            $('#post').html(html);
        })
            .fail(function () {
            console.debug("fail");
        });
});
```

Comment: why should you get a `GET` response when you have a `POST` request? everything seems to work fine with your code and your fiddle, i really don't know what this question is about.

Comment: I guess I'm just a bit confused... I feel like if I were to set this up in an application where the JSON was built up in another page and returned, that it wouldn't work as it does now.  To me, it looks like it's only working because the JSON item is built on this page where it's directly accessible by the AJAX deferred methods

Comment: oh wait - now I have seen it - you are using the variable `item` directly in your `$.each` function. why not use `data.Stores`, cause `data` is what you get from your ajax.

Comment: well, i can't make it work either. I never liked to use ajax in jsfiddle. why not just try it on your computer? there should be no problem with accessing a file with json in it locally.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to set that up.  So all I should have to change is 'item' to 'data' to access the response?

Comment: `console.log` the `data` (in Chrome for example) - and see.